# Why my rects(bases) are colliding, however they aren't in the pygame window?

Tags: python, pygame

I am using `pygame.rect.collidedirect` to ensure no one rect is colliding. When I run it it is showing yes in the terminal it means that rects are colliding but I cannot figure out where are they colliding, but how ever in the pyagme window everything is perfect.

```
import pygame
from random import randint
pygame.init()

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((350,675))
pygame.display.set_caption("First Game")

x_poss = randint(0,350)
y_poss = randint(0,675)
width = 20
height = 20
vel = 8

bases = []

red = (255,0,0)

image_1 = pygame.image.load('bird.png').convert_alpha()
image_2 = pygame.image.load('base.png').convert_alpha()
image_3 = pygame.image.load('base2.png').convert_alpha()
image_4 = pygame.image.load('enemy.png').convert_alpha()

isJump = False
jumpCount = 10
run = True

def draw_rect(color, x, y, width, height):
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, color, (x,y,width, height))

for i in range(5):
    bases.append(pygame.draw.rect(screen, (255,255,255), (randint(0,330), randint(0,675), width, height)))
    bases.append(pygame.draw.rect(screen, (255,255,255), (randint(0,330), randint(0,675), width, height)))


while run:
    pygame.time.delay(50)

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False

    key = pygame.key.get_pressed()

    if key[pygame.K_LEFT] and x_poss > vel - width:
        x_poss -= vel

    if key[pygame.K_RIGHT] and x_poss < 350 - vel - width:
        x_poss += vel

    if not(isJump):
        if key[pygame.K_UP] and y_poss > vel:
            y_poss -= vel

        if key[pygame.K_DOWN] and y_poss < 670 - height - vel:
            y_poss += vel

        if key[pygame.K_SPACE]:
            isJump = True
    else:
        if jumpCount >= -10:
            y_poss -= (jumpCount * abs(jumpCount)) * 0.5
            jumpCount -= 1
        else:
            jumpCount = 10
            isJump = False

    screen.fill((255,255,255))


    for base_1 in bases[:5]:
        screen.blit(image_2, base_1)
    for base_2 in bases[5:]:
        screen.blit(image_3, base_2)
    #Here is the problem......
    for base_2 in bases:
        for base_1 in bases:
            if base_1.colliderect(base_2):
                print('yes')
    #till here i think so....
    

    draw_rect((0,0,0),300, 440, 10, 10)
    draw_rect((255,255,255),x_poss, y_poss, width, height)

    screen.blit(image_4, pygame.draw.rect(screen, (0,0,0), (300,440,10,10)))
    screen.blit(image_1, pygame.draw.rect(screen, (255,255,255), (x_poss, y_poss, width, height)))
    pygame.display.update()

pygame.quit()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rectangles are colliding with itself. You have to ensure that `base_1 != base_2`:

```py
for base_2 in bases:
    for base_1 in bases:
        if base_1 != base_2 and if base_1.colliderect(base_2):
            print('yes')
```

The collision test can be further optimized:

```py
for i, base_2 in enumerate(bases):
    for base_1 in bases[i+1:]:
        if base_1.colliderect(base_2):
            print('yes')
```

and simplified by the use of [`collidelist()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html#pygame.Rect.collidelist):

```py
for i, base in enumerate(bases):
    if base.collidelist(bases[i+1:]) >= 0:
        print('yes')
```

Comment: Thank you for the help...........You can also help me on the latest question asked by me today

Comment: How can we chat

Comment: i got 21 points and now i can chat but how?